# No option to Detect or change Data Type/schema in Copy Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm attempting to get data from a .json blob, detect column data types & save to a table, Cosmosdb or another location. The json columns have no type, and are all imported as strings.

I don't see/have the "detect data type" button on the copy activity, the data flow, or the source data type. Additionally, I don't have the ability to manually change column types.

I'm uncertain if I took an action to trigger a restriction etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Q:I don't see/have the "detect data type" button on the copy activity,
>   the data flow, or the source data type. Additionally, I don't have the
>   ability to manually change column types.

Based on the [document statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#data-type-mapping),ADF supports convert data type from source to sink:

> Copy activity performs source types to sink types mapping with the
>   following 2-step approach:
>
> 1.Convert from native source types to Azure Data Factory interim data types
>   2.Convert from Azure Data Factory interim data types to native sink type

You could use Import Schemas in ADF UI to set your mapping columns:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think a restriction was using a db location as a copy action sink. I now have the option to adjust data types when using a parquet as a sink. I still don't have an option to auto detect/infer data types though.